# BroadCastreceiver Not Working for incoming SMS in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using dynamic broadcastreceiver to receive SMS It was forking fine upto 4.2.2 But It is Not Working on ANdroid MOTO G (4.4.2)

What can be wrong with my Implementation?

```
IntentFilter filter1= new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        filter1.setPriority(2147483647);
        ctx.registerReceiver(messageReceiver, filter1);
```

Comment: maybe the priority of your receiver is not the highest and another SMS app consumes the message.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem as you , a few weeks ago. Now it is working , I have just changed the priority (before it was working even with hard-coded priority, like what you did...)

```
// filter for teh sms receiving
    intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    // intent filter priority
    intentFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);

registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

I hope this helps you.
good luck